# Classes and updating instances

Tags: python, pygame

I have been trying to use classes for the first time on my program but I am struggling when it comes to updating the attributes of my class.

I have been using the pygame library in python for this and I am attempting to use classes to shoot a laser from one point of the screen upwards. However, the laser stays in its position and doesn't manage to go up at all. I am unsure of what to do.

## The size of window: 800 x 600

```
class Mechanics(Display):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.laserX_change = 0
        self.laserY_change = 10
        self.userX_change = 0
        self.userX = 360
        self.laserX = 0
        self.laserY = 480
        self.laser_position = 'active'
        self.laserImg = pygame.image.load('laser.png')

   def fireLaser(self):

        self.laserY -= self.laserY_change

        if self.laserY <= 0:
            self.laserY = 480
            self.laser_position = 'active'

   def activateLaser(self):

        screen.blit(self.laserImg, (self.laserX + 16, self.laserY + 10))
        self.fireLaser()
```

## here is where you use the space bar to use the sound effect and make it go in the same trajectory when the user moves

class Running(Mechanics):

```
def __init__(self):
    Mechanics.__init__(self)



def run(self):

    if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
        if self.laser_position == 'active':
            self.laserX = self.userX
            laserSound = mixer.Sound('shoot.wav')
            laserSound.play()
            self.activateLaser()
```

Comment: there are additional code inside of that class but i wanted to only show this part only. there is a method on it but i just needed help on updating the attributes on fireLaser(). sorry about that. the rest is not needed though that is why.

Comment: Also, the line below the class Running is supposed to be  under but it wont fix and i am new to this :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to understand between a class "definition" and an "Instance" of a class.  Say I define a class to hold colour information:

```
class Colour:
    def __init__( self, r, g, b, a=0 ):
        self.red   = r
        self.green = g
        self.blue  = b
        self.alpha = a
```

That's all it is, a definition.  One would *not* normally write `Colour.red = 33`, since this is the definition of colour, not an instance of it.  Think of the definition like the plans for an empty packing container.  You have to make one before you can start changing its content.  So we make one:

```
purple = Colour( 24, 64, 319 )
```

So now `purple` is an "instance" of a `Colour`.  We can change purple:

```
# make purple darker
purple.red   -= 20
purple.green -= 20
purple.blue  -= 20
```

This is what you need to do with your `Mechanics` (Laser) class, create an instance of it, then change that.   But first I'd like to tweak the class a little:

```
class Laser():
    def __init__( self, x, y=480, x_change=0, y_change=10 ):
        self.laserX = x
        self.laserY = y
        self.laserX_change = x_change
        self.laserY_change = y_change
        self.image = pygame.image.load('laser.png').convert_alpha()
        self.rect  = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = ( x, y )
        self.sound = mixer.Sound('shoot.wav')

    def soundEffect( self ):
        self.sound.play()  # pew! pew!

    def draw( self, window ):
        window.blit( self.image, self.rect )

    def update( self ):
        self.laserX += self.laserX_change
        self.laserY += self.laserY_change
        self.rect.move_ip( self.laserX_change, self.laserY_change )
```

This allows us to create a `Laser` at the given (x,y) co-ordinates.  This class layout is really handy for creating game elements like lasers/bullets/etc. because when activated, the code can just create a new instance of the class at the player's co-ordinates:

```
def run(self):
    if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
        if self.laser_position == None:
            self.laser_position = Laser( self.userX )
            self.laser_position.soundEffect()
            # when laser hits, goes off-screen, etc. 
            # self self.laser_position back to None
```

Notice that at no time did I directly adjust the member variables of the class from outside the class.  This is the normal way in languages other than Python, and doing otherwise would be frowned upon (and make for a poor code review), but in Python it's somehow more acceptable.  Still: don't do it.

WHAT! Why!? Well back to the colour example.  A naïve user of the colour class might do something like:

```
# make a REALLY DARK purple
purple.red   -= 200
purple.green -= 200
purple.blue  -= 200
```

Giving us a purple with a `.red` component of `-176` (24 - 200) which is not a valid colour.  A better approach is to have a function in the class that handled this, because it's the expert on its own internal state:

```
class Colour:
    #...
    def makeDarker( self, delta ):
        self.red   = min( 0, self.red   - delta )
        self.green = min( 0, self.green - delta )
        self.blue  = min( 0, self.blue  - delta )
```

In other languages, internal member variables are often set to "private" so it's not possible to access the directly.  But that's another answer.

One final note:  In the above code, I've mirrored what was in the question, but also added a PyGame `Rect` to your class.  [PyGame Rects are great](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) because the include the co-ordinates as well as the dimensions of your laser image.  They can be easily used with both [collisions](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.collidepoint) and drawing.  So you don't need to maintain a separate X & Y for your objects, just keep it all inside a Rect.

```
class Laser:
    # ...
    def hitPlayer( self, player_rect ):
        is_overlapping = self.rect.colliderect( player_rect )
        return is_overlapping
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That was very helpful. If you can, there is one more little thing. I am new to classes as i mentioned and i am used to using procedural. How would use all the methods in the class Laser and make the laser ascend when it is drawn onto the screen?

Comment: @Penguin2020 - This is the `Laser.update()` function.  For every instance of `Laser` your have, call `.update()`  each frame (maybe put them in a list).  The `Laser.__init__()` already defaults `y_change` to 10, so it should speed down the screen.  You will need to add code to stop/kill the laser once it goes off screen though.

Comment: I see, thank you. I have the laser sound and the laser itself drawn onto the screen but it just won't move anywhere on the update(self): method

Comment: @Penguin2020 - During the `.update()` print out the `self.rect.x` and `self.rect.y`.  Maybe it's being reset somehow.

Comment: Ok it is hitting the Y coordinate 0 at the top of the screen. However, it doesn't seem to show the laser going to there even when drawn

Comment: @Penguin2020 - It's probably best to ask a new question with the laser-moving code.